# Call XF86MonBrightnessUp and XF86MonBrightnessDown from terminal

Tags: fedora, x11, i3, backlight

I am running Qubes OS based on Fedora 36, and using i3wm. I am working on creating an i3 block similar to [this contributed blocklet](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks-contrib/blob/master/backlight/backlight), but without using `xbacklight`.

Why not `xbacklight`? My laptop has brightness increase and decrease fn keys (i.e., `XF86MonBrightnessUp` and `XF86MonBrightnessDown`) which work! I do not have `xbacklight` installed, and I do not want to install additional packages, because clearly my brightness controls work.

1. What I want to do is determine what command my `XF86MonBrightnessUp` and `XF86MonBrightnessDown` keys are sending (such that I could run it from terminal)? Using that, I will update my i3blocks script.

I've tried using `xev`, but it does not seem to give me very useful info.

2. Would also be great if there is a way to determine current brightness level (again, without additional packages).

Ideally, I want to control the brightness in a way that is most battery efficient, and I assume that's what `XF86MonBrightnessUp` and `XF86MonBrightnessDown` do already by default, and while not necessarily so with other packages.

Comment: In which desktop environment can you control the brightness with the Fn key? If it is i3, the appropriate media keys must have already been bound in your configuration, `~/.config/i3/config`. You can check and see what command it executes.

Comment: @C.Aknesil - I am not using a desktop environment, I am using i3. And I have NOT bound these media keys in my `~/.config/i3/config` file.

This is essentially exactly why I am asking - I want to know what these keys are already bound to (and it is NOT currently done via my i3 config), so I can update my i3 config to match

Comment: It's wierd that XF86MonBrightnessUp and XF86MonBrightnessDown work in i3 without you binding them in `~/.config/i3/config`. As far as I know, it's the desktop environment (or i3 window manager in your case) that defines the functionality of the media keys. Also, I am not sure if Xorg is capable of "consuming" the keyboard inputs rather than mapping them according to a layout and passing them above to the desktop/window manager, which either "consumes" them or also passes them above to the application controlling the focussed window.